# JSON call back function name in getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, jsonp

I want to access [REACTOME REST API](http://reactomews.oicr.on.ca:8080/ReactomeRESTfulAPI/ReactomeRESTFulAPI.html) to retrieve some data. I am using `getJSON()` to get the `JSON` data. But I don't know the `callback function name` as the name are different for every websites.

Following is not working:

```
    $.getJSON('http://reactomews.oicr.on.ca:8080/ReactomeRESTfulAPI/RESTfulWS/frontPageItems/homo+sapiens?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {

console.dir(data); });
```

I tried using AJAX too since the jQuery documentation states that we can leave on jQuery to decide the callback function.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://reactomews.oicr.on.ca:8080/ReactomeRESTfulAPI/RESTfulWS/frontPageItems/homo+sapiens',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
       console.dir(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log("error");
```

Comment: hmm when i go to that link all i see is xml, not json, why is that?

Comment: you need to sent the request header `Accepts: application/json`

Comment: @1337holiday default is XML. You can set JSON as data type too. The JSON file is getting downloaded as shown by Chrome developer console.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Done that. Still showing error in console

Comment: what is the error, can you post it?

Comment: it is a parse error, checkout http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hC7pT/2/

Comment: Also I don't see any documentation which says the  REACTOME REST API supports jsonp

Comment: @ArunPJohny Well that wasn't showing in my browser. But how to resolve it because Chrome is downloading the JSON file in the proper format

Comment: @ArunPJohny is right, the problem could definitely be the `Accept` is missing and you are accidentally trying to parse XML

Comment: @ArunPJohny But then how can I get the JSON from jQuery? Cross domain resource issue without jsonp

Comment: Are you sure the site supports JSONP? The documentation doesn't mention anything about JSONP, only JSON.

Comment: @slebetman I have mailed the dev. waiting for a reply. I think it does not supports JSONP

Answer (score 1):

All signs point to the service **not** supporting JSONP.

The actual error in jQuery being: `TypeError: Property 'message' of object Error: jQuery191005664544063620269_1366270377427 was not called is not a function`.

Examining the response from the server when issuing a JSONP request, it is *NOT* wrapped in a callback function. So it returns this...

```
[ {
  "dbId" : 109581,
  "displayName" : "Apoptosis",
  "created" : {
    "dbId" : 109608,
....
```

But to support JSONP it would need to instead be like:

```
jQuery191005664544063620269_1366270377427([ {
  "dbId" : 109581,
  "displayName" : "Apoptosis",
  "created" : {
    "dbId" : 109608,
....)
```

You'll need to find a different way to deal with [same origin security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions.

The simplest option might be to use a server-side proxy instead of going direct via the browser. In other words, jQuery will call a server under your own control (preferably on the same domain as is serving the HTML), and it will then pass the service request on and provide an appropriate response. Or if you don't need to be dynamic on the client, just server-side script the whole thing (ASP.NET, php, etc.)

Comment: I'd prefer that people stop calling cross domain requests CORS. CORS is one very specific mechanism if doing cross domain requests. Another, as you mentioned is to proxy the request instead of using CORS. Yet another is to use JSONP instead of using CORS.

Comment: @slebetman While we're granting wishes, can I get a house on the banks of the Rhine? No? Oh well, at least I can edit my answer...

Answer (score 0):

if the website does not support jsonp i suggest you use server-side script , here is an example using php

http://momotaroblogger.blogspot.co.nz/